# Why does dereferencing `Arc<T> where T : MyTrait` align to 0x10?

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, micro-optimization

I'm over-micro-optimizing my library, and I was looking at generated ASM. I noticed that calling a method of `Arc<T> where T : MyTrait` produces something that I believe is aligning the pointer stored in `ArcInner` to 0x10.

I've reproduced it with this code:

```
#![feature(test)]
extern crate test;

use std::sync::Arc;

struct DA;

trait Drain {
    fn log(&self, &DA);
}

struct BlackBoxDrain;

impl Drain for BlackBoxDrain {
    fn log(&self, da: &DA) {
        test::black_box::<&DA>(da);
    }
}

fn f(d: Arc<Drain>) {
    d.log(&DA)
}

fn main() {
    let arc_d = Arc::new(BlackBoxDrain);
    f(arc_d);
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ac0c6712c4eac257c5e06437e35e3b33&version=nightly&backtrace=2) (Set Nightly + Release and click ASM)

The ASM code in question is:

```
movq    16(%r15), %rdi
leaq    15(%rdi), %rax
negq    %rdi
andq    %rax, %rdi
addq    %r14, %rdi
```

It's important that this operation be as fast as possible. Since the ASM dereference is 5 instructions, and 3 of them seem potentially needless, I'd like to understand why is this happening and if I can help it. Maybe I just don't understand the assembler instructions here.

Edit: My minimal example is not exactly the same, as it looks like crate boundary is required to prevent compiler/linker for optimizing out that sequence. But the sequence is exactly the same in my case, in a tight (rust bench) loop, there are no destructors involved: only a method call on a `Arc<TraitObject>`.

Comment: Since you are optimizing, you do know that number of instructions does not necessarily correlate with program speed? For example, going to vectorized instructions might require more instructions, and yet process more bytes per cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chris Emerson's answer I realized it has something to do with vtable and alignment rules. Then I asked around on Mozilla's Rust IRC channel and aatch and talchas figured it out:

`rustc` will always calculate aligned offset for the data (`T`) stored in the `ArcInner<T>` - since it can be different for each `struct` implementing `T`. This is not a big deal - since these instructions are very fast, and will be subject to good instruction level CPU pararelization.

Comment: I've updated my answer to be a bit more accurate, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That instruction sequence (at least when I run it) is in the function `_ZN33_$LT$alloc..arc..Arc$LT$T$GT$$GT$9drop_slow17h09d36c48f370a93dE`, which demangles to `<alloc::arc::Arc<T>>::drop_slow`.  This is the deallocation function.  [Looking at the source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/arc.rs.html#448):

```
unsafe fn drop_slow(&mut self) {
    let ptr = *self.ptr;

    // Destroy the data at this time, even though we may not free the box
    // allocation itself (there may still be weak pointers lying around).
    ptr::drop_in_place(&mut (*ptr).data);

    if self.inner().weak.fetch_sub(1, Release) == 1 {
        atomic::fence(Acquire);
        deallocate(ptr as *mut u8, size_of_val(&*ptr), align_of_val(&*ptr))
    }
}
```

The sequence is finding the offset the the `data` member of `ArcInner<T>`, which is defined as (roughly):

```
struct ArcInner<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: atomic::AtomicUSize,  // 64-bit or 8 byte atomic count
    weak: atomic::AtomicUsize,    // ditto
    data: T,                      // The actual data payload.
}
```

As background, a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/raw/struct.TraitObject.html) contains a data pointer and vtable pointer, and the [vtable starts with destructor, size, and alignment](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/peeking-inside-trait-objects/).

Update: correct my understanding thanks to dpc.dw's additional research/answer.

The `data` memeber needs to be aligned suitably for the type `T`.  However, since we're accessing this via `Arc<Trait>`, at this point the compiler doesn't know what that alignment is!  We might have stored a theoretical SIMD type with 64 byte alignment, for example.  However, the fat trait object pointer does contain the alignment, from which the offset to `data` can be computed.  This is what's happening here:

```
// assumption: rbx is pointer to trait object
movq    (%rbx), %r14       // Get the ArcInner data pointer into r14
movq    8(%rbx), %r15      // Get vtable pointer into r15
movq    16(%r15), %rdi     // Load T alignment from vtable into rdi
leaq    15(%rdi), %rax     // rax := align+15
negq    %rdi               // rdi = -rdi (-align)
andq    %rax, %rdi         // rdi = (align+15) & (-align)
addq    %r14, %rdi         // Add now aligned offset to `data` to call drop
callq   *(%r15)            // Call destructor (first entry in vtable in r15)
```

Comment: I think you're right and these instructions come from trait object deallocation. I'll have to re-investigate my original code and double check I just got confused by what were these instructions attriubted to in `kcachegrind`.

Comment: After all, it seems it's not the case in my original program. The destructor there never gets called, yet the alignment calculation sequence is there. It seems to me it's just llvm optimizer failing somewhere.

Comment: Could it be that calling a method on any trait object requires 0x10 alignment. eg to lookup vtable (or something in it)?